# Action_Send how is the right way to do it?

Tags: android, android-intent, action, share, send

Hi I want to do the following thing in my app: When the user press the send button it saves the camera preview image and then the user is able to send to some other devices. So far my code is the following one:

```
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/flash_on");

            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");                                                                                                                                 
            //Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
        }
     });
```

Just testing using the image flash_on.png for example and couldn't send right.
My manifest file has:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
```

And:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: How are you trying to send it to another device? Via NFC, Bluetooth, WiFi, or a specific app?

Comment: Now I am testing by Bluetooth but the objective is to send by email, facebook and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            i.setType("image/*");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share image using"));
```